# How to use Mysql commands with ClearDB in Heroku?

Tags: php, mysql, heroku, cleardb

I'm using `ClearDB` with `Heroku`.
I managed to make the migrations that I needed but when I can't find the way to execute queries using the terminal as below:

`SELECT * from table` .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

Format:

```
mysql -h host -uuser -ppassword
```

example:

```
mysql -h us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com -ubxxxxxx7 -p3xxxxxxx
```

**How to find login info**

Use this command in your heroku repo: `heroku config`

Look for the `CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL`

Format:

```
mysql://**user**:**password**@**host**/heroku_db_name?...
```

Example:

```
mysql://bxxxxxx7:3xxxxxxx@us-cdbr-east.cleardb.com/heroku_xxxxxx?...
```

After connecting, just `USE heroku_db_name` and query away!